# How to encode 3 integers into 2 integers?

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, mapping

I have three integers `(x1,x2,x3)` all in `[0,255]`. I need to encode them into two integers (`a`, and `b`) such that I can deterministically decode them back. The constraint is that the size of the new integers needs to be small.
So I can do `a=256*x1+x2`, but this makes `a` much larger than `xi`.

Any way to encode integers such that the resulting numbers stay small?
I am not defining what small is, as I want as small as possible.

A similar problem is to encode these `3` numbers into just `1`. Again the new integer needs to be as small as possible. Any way to do this?

Comment: No, that would would violate the laws of information theory. If you have three full entropy integers in [0,255] and no additional information then you'll need at least 24 bits to store them no matter how you encode them.

Comment: All your 3 values need 8 bits, you can store them in two 12bit variables or one 24bit variable. There is no way to use less bits without loosing information (making reversing impossible for at least some cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to information theory / the pigeonhole principle.  If you wish to encode `x` different values, you need to have enough bits to distinguish between `x` different things.  In your case there are `256 = 2**8` possibilities (using `**` for exponentiation) for each of `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.  Therefore in total there are `2**24` possibilities for the combination.  Therefore you will need `2**24` combinations.  So `24` bits.

Your first encoding can be achieved using 12 bit numbers in the range `0-4095`.  And your encoding can be done as follows (where `%` is the remainder operation and `//` is integer division, as they are in Python3):

```
a = (x1%16) * 256 + x2
b = (x1//16) * 256 + x3
```

with a decoding of:

```
x1 = (a//256) + (b//256) * 16
x2 = a%256
x3 = b%256
```

Encoding into 1 number again needs `2**24` possibilities, so that number needs to be in the range `0..16777215`.  And the encoding this time is:

```
c = x1 + 256*x2 + 65536*x3
```

with a decoding of

```
x1 = c%256
x2 = (c//256)%256
x3 = c//65536
```

There are various other encodings/decodings that you can achieve.  But they can't be achieved with smaller ranges of numbers than that.

Comment: Can you edit your code segments? They seem to contain some typos.

Comment: `x1 = (a//256) + (b//4096)` I don't think so. ((b//256)*16)